how to use IntelliJ IDEA Structural Replace to replace varargs？
Here's what needs to be changed
modifyMethod(String.format(MyClass.myMethod1(),arg1, arg2, arg3...));

Modify it to:
modifyMethod(MyClass,new Object[]{arg1, arg2, arg3...});

My solution:
Search template:
modifyMethod(String.format($MyClass$.myMethod1(),$Parameter$));
(where Count for $Parameter$ = [1, Unlimited])

Replace template: modifyMethod($MyClass$,new Object[]{$Parameter$}); 
(where Count for $Parameter$ = [1, Unlimited])

But there's a problem that the commas inside the curly braces are gone.
for example,
modifyMethod(String.format(MyClass.myMethod1(),arg1, arg2, arg3));

modifyMethod(MyClass,new Object[]{arg1arg2arg3});

How should I fix this or if there is a better solution?
